# overlap points(or symbols) in a raster with levelplot

Tags: r

I would like to ask some help for plotting a matrix(converted to raster) and overlay with symbols another one. For that, I was trying to use layer (and sp.points), as in several examples that I have read...but I am not very familiar with that and I am missing something. This would be the main idea. I will put a reproducible example (since the real data are more complex).

```
        #Create 1 matrix
        m1 <- matrix(runif(100),nrow=10,ncol=20)
        #create 2 matrix 
        m2 <- matrix(1:4,nrow=10,ncol=20)

        #Convert to raster
        M1<- stack(raster(m1))
        #plot
        p<-levelplot(M1, margin=FALSE)

        #For the second matrix
         xy<-melt(m2)
        #Add the layer
        p +layer(sp.points(xy, pch=1:4)
```

I am aware that this is wrong..but I don't know how to plot it...
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a couple of ideas/alternatives that might be of use:

```
m1 <- matrix(runif(100),nrow=10,ncol=20)
m2 <- matrix(1:4,nrow=10,ncol=20)

library(raster)
M1 <- raster(m1)
M2 <- raster(m2)

plot(M1)
text(M2)   

pts <- cbind(xyFromCell(M1, 1:ncell(M1)), value=as.vector(t(m2)))

plot(M1)
cols=rainbow(4)[pts[,3]]
points(pts)
points(pts, col=cols, pch=20)

xy <- SpatialPoints(pts[,1:2])

library(rasterVis)
p <-levelplot(M1, margin=FALSE)
p + layer(sp.points(xy, pch=1:4))

spplot(M1, sp.layout = list("sp.points", xy, pch=1:4))
```

Comment: Great idea!! thanks a lot!! it seems to work with my real data :) , both cases are perfect..I can use the number or symbols!, many thanks again!